# How do I calculate the wholesale price, if I have the retail price and the wholesale markup %?

Tags: percentages

Given that I have the retail price & desired retail markup % of an item, how do I then calculate the wholesale price?

Say the following is true for a cup:

Retail: $100

Desired Markup: 100%

Wholesale: $???

Instinctively I know that the Wholesale price should be `$50`, because I know that marking up `$50` by `100%` would give me `$100`.

But how do I calculate that in a formula, such that I could enter that formula into a 'Wholesale' field in Excel and have it reference the Retail price and the Desired Markup and then get the correct wholesale price?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applying a markup of $n$% to a base amount is the same as multiplying the base amount by
$$\frac{100 + n}{100}$$
To remove the markup, just multiply the marked up amount by
$$\frac{100}{100+n}$$

Comment: Technically, what worked for me in Excel was (1/1+n). But thanks for pointing me in the right direction.